# Redux persistedState object is not setting default redux state

Tags: redux

I have the following code:

```
    const persistedState = window.localStorage.getItem(DEFAULT_LOCALSTORAGE_NAME)
                              ? JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem(DEFAULT_LOCALSTORAGE_NAME))
                              : {};

    const store = createStore(rootReducer, persistedState, enhancer);

    console.log('persisted state', persistedState);
    console.log('stringified store', JSON.stringify(store.getState()));
```

In the console however, I see the following result:

[image]

Any idea why the state is not correctly set (it uses the initial state that I set on my reducer)?

Comment: What `enhancer` do you use?
DId you try to step in to `createStore` function to see what really happens?

Comment: @Fyodor I already fixed the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem quite easily by refactoring the reducers: I applyed a flat structure and split up my current reducer using combinereducers.
Reducers require pure functions without side effect, so actually it was more correct to do it this way anyhow.